# Capitalising interpolated language keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next

**The problem:**

With i18next you can interpolate variables into your string like `"AddNew": "Add new {{item}}"` Now I have a language where the grammar requires the {{item}} needs to be the first word like `"AddNew": "{{item}} toevoegen"`.

In the [docs](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting) they show some support for formatting, but these are all related to dates or numbers. I am looking for a way to add a capitalisation formatting function e.g: `"AddNew": "{{item, capitalise }} toevoegen"`

**What I have so far but isn't working**

A function that capitalises the first letter.

```
export function capitalizeFirstLetter(string: string): string {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
};
```

And attempting to add it to the formatters

```
i18n.services.formatter?.add('capitalize', (value, lng, options) => {
    return capitalizeFirstLetter(value);
});
```

Now I had to add a `?` after `.formatter` for TS to not complain. But I'd guess that this is also the issue, `formatter` is undefined. I can only import Formatter and Services with a capital letter from the i18next library, so I'm a bit lost on how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add your custom formatter AFTER you called `i18next.init()`: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting#adding-custom-format-function

[image]

Comment: This was indeed the issue, many thanks